# How to solve Invalid element(s) received for the 'color' property?

Tags: python, css, plotly-dash

I have a piece of code that gives various colours to scatterplot dots based on the hour of the day wherein they were observed. This is done per this code:

```
color=listCoords.index.hour
```

In the contextual code:

```
return go.Figure(
        data=[
            # Data for all observations based on date and time
            Scattermapbox(
                lat=listCoords["Lat"],
                lon=listCoords["Lon"],
                mode="markers",
                hoverinfo="text + lat + lon",
                text=listCoords.index.hour,
                marker=dict(
                    showscale=True,
                    color=listCoords.index.hour,
                    opacity=np.where((listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), 0.1, 0.7), 
                    size=np.where((listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), 20, 7),
                    colorscale=[
                        [0, "#F4EC15"],
                        [0.04167, "#DAF017"],
                        [0.0833, "#BBEC19"],
                        [0.125, "#9DE81B"],
                        [0.1667, "#80E41D"],
                        [0.2083, "#66E01F"],
                        [0.25, "#4CDC20"],
                        [0.292, "#34D822"],
                        [0.333, "#24D249"],
                        [0.375, "#25D042"],
                        [0.4167, "#26CC58"],
                        [0.4583, "#28C86D"],
                        [0.50, "#29C481"],
                        [0.54167, "#2AC093"],
                        [0.5833, "#2BBCA4"],
                        [1.0, "#613099"],
                    ],
                    colorbar=dict(
                        title="Time of<br>Day",
                        x=0.93,
                        xpad=0,
                        nticks=24,
                        tickfont=dict(color="#d8d8d8"),
                        titlefont=dict(color="#d8d8d8"),
                        thicknessmode="pixels",
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

I want to change 'color=' into:

```
color=np.where((listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), 'red', listCoords.index.hour)
```

> so that the dots become 'red' if their 'Threat' value equals '3'
>   otherwise "color" should just be 'listCoords.index.hour'

But this new code update gives:

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'color' property of scattermapbox.marker
        Invalid elements include: ['4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4']

    The 'color' property is a color and may be specified as:
      - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
      - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
      - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
      - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
      - A named CSS color:
            aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,
            beige, bisque, black, blanchedalmond, blue,
            blueviolet, brown, burlywood, cadetblue,
            chartreuse, chocolate, coral, cornflowerblue....
```

> **QUESTION:** So yes, it is expecting a CSS color obviously. But seeing that initially 'color=' did consider `listCoords.index.hour` as
>   a value, how can I make this item consider that value again if not
>   'red'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLUTION:

With the following piece applied:

```
color=np.where((listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), 'red', listCoords.index.hour)
```

It outputted the error:

```
ValueError: 
    Invalid element(s) received for the 'color' property of scattermapbox.marker
        Invalid elements include: ['4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4', '4']

    The 'color' property is a color and may be specified as:
      - A hex string (e.g. '#ff0000')
      - An rgb/rgba string (e.g. 'rgb(255,0,0)')
      - An hsl/hsla string (e.g. 'hsl(0,100%,50%)')
      - An hsv/hsva string (e.g. 'hsv(0,100%,100%)')
      - A named CSS color:
            aliceblue, antiquewhite, aqua, aquamarine, azure,
            beige, bisque, black, blanchedalmond, blue,
            blueviolet, brown, burlywood, cadetblue,
            chartreuse, chocolate, coral, cornflowerblue....
```

To solve this, I altered the colorscale by saying that 0 = 'red' (#FF0000).

Subsequently, I said that if ('Threat == 3' give 0) else give regular colours.

My new code (only parts that have been updated):

```
    red = 0
    mycolors = np.where((listCoords['Threat'] == '3'), red, listCoords.index.hour)
    print(mycolors)
```

and

```
  color=np.array(mycolors, int),
                colorscale=[
                    [0, "#FF0000"],
                    [0.04167, "#DAF017"],
                    [0.0833, "#BBEC19"],
                    [0.125, "#9DE81B"],
                    [0.1667, "#80E41D"],
                    [0.2083, "#66E01F"],
                    [0.25, "#4CDC20"],
                    [0.292, "#34D822"],
                    [0.333, "#24D249"],
                    [0.375, "#25D042"],
                    [0.4167, "#26CC58"],
                    [0.4583, "#28C86D"],
                    [0.50, "#29C481"],
                    [0.54167, "#2AC093"],
                    [0.5833, "#2BBCA4"],
                    [1.0, "#613099"],
                ],
```